# how to implement progress bar for function in service and controller to show the status in grails platform

Tags: grails, progress

I am working on grails. I have a controller it calls service to check the value and one more call to do some calculation, by the time i want user to know its processing the function. Since i am new to grails , i dont know how to implement this in my project. I tried few plugins but i didnt know how to approach this by using plugin(Step by step). I need easiest way to solve this problem even this my ajax or javascript. i searched online i didnt get one. 
Please help me to solve this .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Grails by default allows you to call controller methods with Ajax by default, you simply need to use the remoteFunction tag (http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html).

You use this by specifying an element on your page which will be updated by the html that you controller function returns, usually a gsp template.

For example, you could have your controller call the service to check for progress, and then the controller passes this returned progress amount to your gsp template. You use this value to draw a percentage, and return that html to your original page (this is whatever the controller returns - the remoteFunction tag handles the updating for you).

I suggest having a look for some examples of the remoteFunction call and going from there.
Hope that helps.

Comment: i am calling the function using this tag <g:actionSubmit /> and calling few services to complete the funciton .By using <remote Function> i couldnt use any select statement what i dont want .

Comment: I think you need to do this in two different steps, firstly submit the form to your controller. Secondly, have the controller track the progress in a variable, and use a <remoteFunction> on the page that is loaded after your <g:actionSubmit> to update the progress. If you don't want to go to another page, you can use <g:submitToRemote> so that the progress bar can be shown on your save page. Sorry if i have misunderstood you.

Comment: sorry, if i  confused you. problem is ,though i use <remote function> i couldnt pass the list of params from the forms to controller . I display or allow user to enter the list of items, after clicking it , it shows the progress bar for a while , it stops because i need the params list to proceed further.<g:remoteLink action="statusRegistration2Validate"  update="success"onLoading="showSpinner();" method="GET" params="${[beacon:beaconList,easting:eastingList]}">remoteLink</g:remoteLink>.I display the list items from the table by using each tag